# On an Uncertainty Relation for Angular Variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm looking for a proof of the Angular Momentum - Angle uncertainty relation $$\frac{\Delta L \Delta \theta}{1-(3/\pi^2)\Delta \theta^2} \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$
which does not involve solving the differential equation for the parabolic cylinder functions (such a derivation was originally given by M. Bouten, N. Maene and P. Van Leuven). Does such a proof even exist?